# Stop encoding of '?' during JSON cross domain request

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

How can I prevent a cross domain jQuery `getJSON` request from encoding the callback question mark:

```
$.getJSON(searchResultsURL, {
        token: jSONAPItoken,
        callback: '?'
    }, function(data){
        ……
    })
```

Ends up sending a request:
`http://example.com/xxx?token=tokenxxx&callback=%3F`

Where is it encoding the `?` to `%3f`. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mis-using `getJSON`.

`$.getJSON` requires that the `callback` parameter be in the URL, not the `data` argument.

You need to add `?callback=?` to the URL string; jQuery will then replace the `?` with an auto-generated callback function name.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is not a valid character in a query string, and MUST be encoded. However, the server decodes it before passing it to your server side (so for example in PHP `$_GET['callback']` will be equal to `?`)

You shouldn't be concerned about this because it's just a silent operation to format your URL so it will actually work.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the issue.